# Laravel 5.2 Authentication - Auth::user() returns NULL

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

In my controller, `Auth::attempt($userdata)` works  successfully but while printing `Auth::user()` in other functions, it returns NULL. What could be gone wrong?

Here is the route.php

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin'],function(){

/*Admin Login & Reset & Logout Routes*/

Route::get('login',['as'=>'suprlogn','uses'=>'admin\AdminController@index']);
Route::post('dologin',['as'=>'dologin','before'=>'csrf','uses'=>'admin\AdminController@dologin']);

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    Route::get('dashboard',['as'=>'dashboard','uses'=>'admin\AdminController@dashboard']);
   });

});
```

and my AdminController.php is this:

```
public function dologin(){ 
     $userdata=array(
        'username'=>Request::get('username'),   
        'password'=>Request::get('password')  
        );

    if(Auth::attempt($userdata)){
        // var_dump(Auth::user()); 
        return Redirect::to(route('dashboard'));
   } 
}

public function dashboard(){

 if (Auth::check())
    return View::make('admin.dashboard');
 else

    var_dump(Auth::user());exit;
}
```

I've also  changed the HTTP/kernal.php middleware stack as

```
 protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];
```

Its still not working

Comment: Route::GET ?? Is it working ??

Comment: Ive corrected it. still not working